# Ruby on Rails SMS sending

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sms

I'm trying to code for an sms server using this tutorial:

http://lukeredpath.co.uk/blog/sending-sms-messages-from-your-rails-application.html

Here they advice us to use clickatell but i have a gateway that i can use which i would like to use. However i wouldn't know how to write the bits of code that says `require clickatel` or `sudo gem install clickatell`. I'm new to ruby and rails hence any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Use gem 'mvaayoo' easy integration, subscribe http://mvaayoo.com for credentials

Answer (score 7):

I have found twilio easy to use and recommend it. They have a tutorial that works (at least in Rails 3.07).

http://www.twilio.com/

Comment: @B Seven where is this RoR tutorial?

Comment: It seems that they removed most of the Ruby tutorials. Here's an up-to-date demo app for Ruby (not Rails): https://github.com/twilio/twilio-ruby . This shows how to use the API.  I would see if I could get this to work, and then integrate into a Rails app.

Comment: Current blog-tutorial for Rails 4: https://www.twilio.com/blog/2014/02/twilio-on-rails-integrating-twilio-with-your-rails-4-app.html